# Problem with margins when placing an image in header using fancyheader

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr

I am trying to place an image in the header and spacing it 4.5mm from the top of the page and 4.5 mm from the right of the page.

In the TexWorks preview it looks like clearly less than 4.5 mm space:

[image]

But when printing it goes even wronger:

[image]

The top margin is 6mm and the right margin is 3mm.

The code that generates this is this:

In the .sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{exampleStyleSheet}[2020/06/28 Example style LaTeX package]

\RequirePackage{tabularx}




%Logo
\RequirePackage[a4paper, top=0.045cm,right=0.045cm, includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{showframe}
\RequirePackage{layouts}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./logo/} }
\newcommand{\makelogo}{

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\fboxrule=1pt%border thickness
\rhead{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{../logo/BLLogoC.png}}}
\hfill
}
```

And in the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{./exampleStyleSheet}


\begin{document}
\makelogo
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this? Feeling frazzled as I've been trying to do this for hours.

**Edit**
My printer dialogue is auto-set to "shrink to fit" and when I select "actual size" it will be about a cm outside the page both at the top and at the right.

Comment: At least for the right margin margin, you can try adding `\llap`, like this: `\rhead{\llap{\fcolorbox{red}{yellow}{\includegraphics[height=\headheight]{../logo/BLLogoC.png}}}}`

Comment: That places the image in the left margin, to the left of the header.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't test, as I don't have the image, but in theory there are several possibilities, depending on what else, hypothetically, should be in the header.

Comment: In your .sty file, note that 4.5 mm = 0.45 mm, not 0.045. If you change to the correct value the problem dispappears.  Unrelated: I don't see why you load `showframe`, using `geometry`: the latter has a `showframe` option.

Comment: Thank you for your help! In the meantime, I noticed that my printer (or OS, possibly both) adds their own margin values. So I added the 1 in margin into my document definition hoping it would help (and deleted my 0.045 etc.) but I still don't get the margins that I specify.